# Ошибка после добавления зависимостей kotlinx-serialization

Tags: android, kotlin, serializable, kotlinx-serialization

Я попытался добавить зависимости библиотеки `Serialization` по инструкции с гитхаба (https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#android), но видимо сделал что-то не так, потому что при синхронизации возникает ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему. Заранее спасибо.

Ошибка:

```
Build file 'C:\Users\Andrew\AndroidStudioProjects\WeatherAppKotlin\app\build.gradle' line: 5

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm']
   > Cannot add extension with name 'kotlin', as there is an extension already registered with that name.
```

build.gradle module

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.4.31'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.andblack.weatherappkotlin"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    // Async
    def coroutines_version = "1.4.1"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"

    // Network
    def retrofit_version = "2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    def okhttp_version = "4.3.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp_version"

    // Kotlinx serialization
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.1.0")

}
```

build.gradle project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.31"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'` не нужен

Comment: @IR42 Спасибо большое! Действительно jvm было лишним. Теперь ошибки нет и аннотации работают.